# Automatically resize an image and adjust it to Grid-/Button Size

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a folder that contains many Image files. In my application there is on the first window many image buttons for each of these images. If you click on a button, then a new window will open, which shows the selected image.

**Problem:**
How can you scale/resize a picture so that it automatically (always) adjusts to the window / button size without loss of quality.

Comment: By setting `Stretch="Uniform"` on the Image control.

Comment: By setting `Stretch="Uniform` the picture does not fill the Grid und with `Stretch="UniformToFill` the picture is greater than the Grid and only and part of the picture is displayed

Comment: You can also set `Stretch="Fill"`, but then the image's aspect ratio isn't kept.

Comment: Is it not possible to display the file in high quality and keep the image's aspect ratio?

Comment: Whatever "display the file in high quality" means, but setting Stretch to `None`, `Uniform` or `UniformToFill` keeps the aspect ratio. It's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: After testing various settings, I found that `UniformToFill` is the setting that I have to use but the only problem is that "If the aspect ratio of the target rectangle differs from the source, the source content is trimmed according to the target dimensions". Is it possible to use `UniformToFill` and scale the image so that it is fully displayed in the Grid?

Comment: Meanwhile you should have understood that you can't have both. At different aspect ratios of the source image and the target viewport, you can't show the full image without distortion and at the same time fill the entire viewport. This is geometrically impossible.